# CSS media query not firing

Tags: css, media-queries

I have three stylesheets: a persistent one, one for windows 800px or greater ("standard"), and one for windows smaller than 800px ("mobile"). My problem is that the standard style sheet is being recognized and applied, but when I resize the window to under 800px, the mobile sheet is ignored and I'm left with only the persistent style. I suspect it's a basic syntax error, but I haven't been able to find the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="persistentstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:800px)" title="standard" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:799px)" title="mobile" href="mobilestyle.css">
```

I already have the necessary meta tag in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, just wrong link to `mobilestyle.css` file?

Comment: Why not just add the media queries "inline" inside your CSS files at the bottom of your main CSS file? Or if you wanted to separate them, put the media query code at the top of the individual files for each different size.

Comment: Your media queries seem OK. Some debugging techniques: 1) check your mobile stylesheet for errors 2) make a `<style media="screen and (max-width:799px)">` and see if any of the rules you place in there will work.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/09/combining_meta.html):-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the most common mistake is not including the meta tag required for CSS media queries to work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

[This link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml) explains the viewport meta tag, and additional properties you can assign to it, such as allowing the screen to be scaled, and more.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I do not that meta tag in the header. I will update my question.